# Flask и Django. Стоит ли переходить?

Tags: python, django, flask

Всем привет, уже год как пишу на **Flask**. Создано уже не одно приложение на **Flask** (не просто одностраничники, а прям полноценные приложения). Но посмотрев на просторы интернета - на вакансиях в основном требуются **Django-разработчики** и все пишут, что на **Django** очень быстро все развертывается. Неужели **Flask** так не популярен уже?

**Собственно сам вопрос:** стоит ли переходить на сторону **Django** при проектировании новых приложений или остаться на стороне **Flask**?

**Хочется узнать мнение ветеранов, которые поработали в обоих фреймворках** и на чем они лично оставили свой выбор и почему.

Comment: Ничто не мешает знать одновременно Django и Flask, я делаю сайты на них обоих, а ещё на aiohttp и Sanic

Comment: Касательно того, что использовать для нового сайта - зависит от целей и задач, для которых этот самый сайт создаётся. На вопрос в текущем его виде невозможно дать объективно верный ответ

Comment: @andreymal, я просто хочу узнать мнение людей, которые съели ни одну собаку на этом. И рано или поздно кто-то все равно оставляет выбор на чем-то одном...

Comment: @АлексейБелкин вопросы с ответами, основанными на мнениях - в принципе оффтопик на stackoverflow.

Comment: `Неужели Flask так не популярен уже?` - не "уже", а он в принципе никогда не был так популярен как Django. В целом - лучше все по возможности попробовать, в том числе самые новые штуки. Вот некоторые уже с Django Rest Framework на FastAPI мигрируют, а вы пока только рассуждаете о Flask и Django)

Comment: Мое мнение такое, что ни то, ни другое вам не нужно. Рассмотрите fastapi или что-нибудь такое же, асинхронное. Я сам начинал с flask, потом какое-то время писал на django. Не совсем понятно, зачем такое награмаждание возможностей есть в этих фреймворках, в частности в джанго... Из-за этого они ужасно медленные

Comment: @Ivan,  Я сейчас начинаю писать новое приложение и по советам из комментов решил попробовать FastApi. Вопрос может, мой глупый будет, но тем не менее: можно ли на нем делать визуальную часть? Видео, которые посмотрел - там ничего про шаблоны не говорится как во Flask. Если можно реализвать, то это через обычный Jinja делать и страницы указывать свои? Не надо никаких особых дирректорий делать на подобии **templates**?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин как следует из названия, FastApi предназначен для создания API, а не визуальной части

Comment: @andreymal, получается, что если в приложении д/б визуальная часть, то тогда это только Flask или Джанго?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин визуальная часть сама по себе не имеет никакого отношения к питону и брать Flask или Django никто не заставляет, вы можете делать её любым удобным вам способом (хоть SPA-сайт на React или Vue, хоть Android-приложение, хоть десктопная программа на Qt, неважно)

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, Я думаю вам стоит еще рассмотреть, что условное приложение всегда делится на backend (логика, работа с БД, и прочее) и frontend (то, какие кнопки жмет пользователь). Если вы хотите прикрутить аналоги шаблонов в fastapi (то есть по сути сделать SSR) - без проблем, но лично я такое не одобряю, так как это у вас логика фронта будет сильно связана с логикой бэка, что позже потом может вам помешать перейти на какой-то другой фронт или что-то такое